# jmeter how to add +4 to the date extracted from the jmeter response using regular expression extractor?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am facing issue while trying to add 4 days to the date extracted from the response.
I have extracted the date using regular expression extractor and placed in a variable depdate . Now i need one more date with +4 of extracted date .

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) **after** the Regular Expression Extractor
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); // change it according to your Date format
   Date originalDate = sdf.parse(vars.get("depdate"));

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(originalDate);

   cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 4); // change it if you need to add something else

   Date newDate = cal.getTime();

   vars.put("newDepdate", sdf.format(newDate));

   log.info("Original date: " + vars.get("depdate"));
   log.info("New date: " + vars.get("newDepdate"));
   ```
3. Refer the new date as `${newDapdate}` where required

---

Remarks:

- Above code assumes date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, i.e. `23/08/2016`. If your date format is different - use your own pattern, check out [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) article for details.
- Above code assumes adding 4 **days** to the current date. If you need to add 4 minutes, hours, months, years, whatever - change `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` to your value, see [Calendar class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for available options
- For anything else check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide